# Convergence of series $\sum \limits^{\infty }_{n=1}\frac{n^{(n+\frac{1}{n} )}}{(n+\frac{1}{n} )^{\frac{1}{n} }}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

i need help for find method or methods for solve this series  and find the convergence.  I very appreciate for any help and yours comments. $$\sum \limits^{\infty }_{n=1}\frac{n^{(n+\frac{1}{n} )}}{(n+\frac{1}{n} )^{\frac{1}{n} }} $$

Comment: That numerator looks to be much larger than the denominator as $n$ grows.

Comment: the denominator goes to $1$ as n goes to $\infty$

Comment: The terms are bounded below by ${n^n n^{1/n}\over2^{1/n} n^{1/n}}$. These terms do not approach zero as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: This is a completely trivial question and I don't see any input from the OP. So it gets my down-vote.

Comment: Ok Ramanujan...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That series is going to diverge because the numerator is close to $n^n$ while the denominator is close to $\sqrt[n]{n}$.  Using the $n$-th term test for divergence:

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^{(n+\frac{1}{n} )}}{(n+\frac{1}{n} )^{\frac{1}{n} }}
$$

We can take the exponential and natural log to find that this limit equals 
$$
e^{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(n+\frac{1}{n})\ln n-\frac{1}{n}\ln(n+\frac{1}{n})}
$$

Consider the exponent:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(n+\frac{1}{n})\ln n-\frac{1}{n}\ln(n+\frac{1}{n})
$$

By rearranging, we have that this is
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\ln n+\frac{1}{n}(\ln n-\ln(n+\frac{1}{n}))
$$

Since $\ln n-\ln(n+\frac{1}{n})=\ln\frac{n}{n+\frac{1}{n}}$, we see that $\frac{n}{n+\frac{1}{n}}$ approaches $1$ as $n$ grows, so this approaches $\ln(1)=0$.  Moreover, the coefficient of $\frac{1}{n}$ also appraches zero, so this means that the second term in the limit above is

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\ln n
$$
which approaches infinity.  Therefore, the limit of the $n$-th terms is $e^{\infty}$ (abusing notation), and so the series diverges.

Answer (score 2):

For $n\ge 2$ we have
$$\left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}< n+\frac{1}{n}< n+1$$
Also, 
$$n^2>n+1$$
Then
$$\frac{n^{n+\frac{1}{n}}}{\left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}}>\frac{n^n}{n+1}>\frac{n^{n-2}(n+1)}{n+1}=n^{n-2}$$
It follows $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{n+\frac{1}{n}}}{\left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$ diverges

Comment: Elegant thanks i very appreciate.

Comment: @user239295: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The general term is divergent so the series diverges:

$\frac{n^{(n+\frac{1}{n} )}}{(n+\frac{1}{n} )^{\frac{1}{n} }}\geq \frac{n^{n}}{(2n)^{\frac{1}{n}}}=\left ( \frac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{n}}} \right )\left ( \frac{n^{n}}{n^{\frac{1}{n}}} \right )\rightarrow \infty $